# Filtering out Non English sentences in a list in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, non-english, pyenchant

So there is a excel file which i have read through pandas and stored it in a dataframe 'df'. Now that excel file contains 24 columns as 'questions' and 631 rows as 'responses/answers'.

So i converted one such question into a list so that i can tokenize it and apply further nlp related tasks on it.

```
df_lst = df['Q8 Why do you say so ?'].values.tolist()
```

Now, this gives me a list that contains 631 sentences, out of which some sentences are non-english.. So i want to filter out the non-english sentences so that in the end I am left with a list that contains only english sentences.

What i have:

```
df_lst = ['The excecutive should be able to understand the customer's problem','Customers should get correct responses to their queries', 'This text is in a random non english language'...]
```

Output (What i want):

```
english_words = ['The excecutive should be able to understand the customer's problem','Customers should get correct responses to their queries', ...]
```

Also, I read about a python library named pyenchant which should be able to do this, but it's not compatible with windows 64bit and python 3.. Is there any other way by which this can be done ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is another library (closely related to nltk), TextBlob,
Initially bound to Sentiment analysis,
But you can still use it for translation, see the doc here: https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html

Section Translation and Language Detection

gl

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered taking advantage of the number of English "stopwords" in your sentences? Give a look at the [`nltk` package](https://www.nltk.org/). Check English stopwords using the following code:

```
import nltk
from ntlk.corpus import stopwords
ntlk.download('stopwords') # If you just installed the package
set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

You could add a new column indicating the number of English stopwords present in each of your sentences. Presence of stopwords could be used as a predictor of English language.

Other thing that could work is, if you know for a fact that most answers are in English to begin with, make a frequency ranking for words (possibly for each question in your data). In your example, it looks like the word "customer" shows up quite consistently for the question under study. So you could engineer a variable that indicates the presence of very frequent words in an answer. That could also serve as a predictor. Do not forget to either make all words lowercase or uppercase and deal with plural or 's so you don't rank "customer", "Customer", "customers", "Customers", "customer's" and "customers'" all as different words.

After engineering the variables above, you can set up a threshold above which you consider the sentence to be written in English, or you can go for something a bit more fancy in terms of unsupervised learning.